# apache nifi: loop over list or using counters

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using apache nifi to implement some workflows which are the same but for 1 or 2 parameters. Before this I used oozie and despite it was about acyclic graphs, there were some tricks to loop over list or counters.
Is the same for nifi ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Koji Kawamura has done examples of looping using counters [here](https://gist.github.com/ijokarumawak/01c4fd2d9291d3e74ec424a581659ca8).